# Apache prefork mode MaxRequestsPerChild?

Tags: apache-2.2

From an article:

"With this prefork model, Apache is managing several child processes, and each process could be used to manage one HTTP request. "

Is this true?

Then why is the:

```
 MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
```

In the config. I guess it's default value 0 means unlimited requests per child but then this means that the first statement is not correct and all of these preforked apache processes can serve multiple requests.

Comment: Of course they can serve multiple requests, but not at once...

Comment: Could you please post your source article?

Answer (score 2):

The docs about `MaxRequestsPerChild` (known as [`MaxConnectionsPerChild`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxconnectionsperchild) as of httpd 2.3.9) is pretty clear

> The MaxConnectionsPerChild directive sets the limit on the number of connections that an individual child server process will handle. After MaxConnectionsPerChild connections, the child process will die. If MaxConnectionsPerChild is 0, then the process will never expire.
>
> Setting MaxConnectionsPerChild to a non-zero value limits the amount of memory that process can consume by (accidental) memory leakage.

Comment: Well this is still not clear to me. Then does it mean that if you set this to lets say 200 then it can serve 200 requests then die and respawn or it can handle 200 simoulteanous requests from clients at the same time? Somebody said that its serialized so then it must be case 1 that if you set this number to 200 then it handles 200 requests from one or more clients then the process will die out. Is this correct?

Comment: MaxRequestsPerChild specifies the maximum number of requests that a single worker can process before being reaped and respawned. These are not concurrent requests.. The setting that specifies how many workers can handle requests concurrently is MaxRequestWorkers. So yes, if set to 200, the process will be killed and respawned after processing 200 requests. It won't just 'die out'.